# How to update js add-in api for office 2016 installed via MSI

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, word-addins, office-2016

I am developing Office 2016 Word and Excel add-ins that require support for API 1.2, my corp users Office 2016 install only supports API 1.1.  I am assuming the corp install was done from an MSI.

- Office updates are disabled
- Any updates I tried to install I get the message 'invalid installer'.

What is required to update their office to support API 1.2?

Regards
Floyd

Comment: I don't know about those API levels, but _"Office updates are disabled"_ and _"What is required to update their office"_ seems like an issue...